# iPhone Safari HTML form 'undefined' is not an object

Tags: javascript, forms

I got two errors when I am trying to change the hidden field value:
1.
Javascript: Error
undefined
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object

1. Javascript: Error
   undefine: 'null' is not an object

Any clue?

```
<input type="hidden" name="submit" value=""/>
<input type="Button" name="button" value="Add draft" onclick="this.form['submit'].value=this.value;">
```

Comment: Note that in JavaScript `foo['bar']` is 100% equivalent to `foo.bar` when `bar` is a valid identifier. As such, even though RobG has correctly shown that you need to change the name, you can write the new code as `this.form.newName.value=this.value`.

Answer (score 2):

Presuming that the controls are actually in a form, the forms's submit method is masking the control named "submit". Give the control some other name. Most browsers will go the other way, setting `form.submit` to reference the control and mask the submit method.

And don't use XML style tags unless you really are using XML or XHTML.